# Conditional constraints in OR SAT google not working as expected

Tags: or-tools

I am new with google OR SAT in python and the documentation is not very clear. What I am trying to do is the following:
There's a list like this:

```
desk[1] = 3
desk[2] = 5
desk[3] = 4
desk[4] = 2
desk[5] = 1
```

and a variable called person_la_croix, with value = 4, let's say.
I would like to create a boolean list (t) out of that t[i] = 1, if desk[i] != person_la_croix and 0 otherwise. And then I would like to take the i from t[i] which t[i] == 1 and assign it to variable desk_la_croix

I tried this:

```
for i in s:
    model.Add(desk[i] == person_la_croix).OnlyEnforceIf(t[i])
for i in s:
    model.Add(desk_la_croix == i).OnlyEnforceIf(t[i])
```

It is not working...
Can someone help me out either with this code or suggesting a smarter way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you read

https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/ortools/sat/doc/channeling.md ?

I guess you miss the opposite of the OnlyEnforceIf as these are only implications, not equivalences.